# Check if table exists in default schema for a user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

In SQL server, how do I check if a table exists in the default schema for a particular user ?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, after substituting `TheTable` with the actual table name you are trying to locate:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA_NAME() 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    --Do Stuff here
END
```

`SCHEMA_NAME()` will return the name of the default schema of the caller. [ [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175068.aspx) ]

Comment: Is there a way to check it for other users as well ?

Comment: Yes. This SQL will give you all your SQL Users (type = 'S') and their default Schema Names. `SELECT name as 'UserName', default_schema_name as 'DefaultSchemaName'FROM sys.database_principals where type = 'S' and default_schema_name IS NOT NULL`. You should then be able to use this in a join with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` using the Schema Name in the JOIN condition and the table name in the `WHERE` clause.